# How to pass std::string to CreateDirectory with Unicode set

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having difficulty with the CreateDirectory function. In the following code I am getting a 
"cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'" compile error for the CreateDirectory call.

```
// make path to folder in program data
char szPath[MAX_PATH];
if ( ! SUCCEEDED( SHGetFolderPathA( NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath ) ) )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Could not open server log - no common data folder " << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
std::string fname = szPath;
fname +="/Point";
CreateDirectory( fname.c_str(), NULL);
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and have "Character Set = Use Unicode Character Set".

In fileapi.h the following is defined:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    #define CreateDirectory  CreateDirectoryW
#else
    #define CreateDirectory  CreateDirectoryA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

So I think the CreateDirectoryW function is being used

What do I need to do to get this to compile properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` in order to use wide character strings.

```
int main()
{
    // make path to folder in program data
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (!SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath)))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not open server log - no common data folder " << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::wstring fname = szPath;
    fname += L"/Point";
    CreateDirectory(fname.c_str(), NULL);
}
```

If you do not want to use wide character strings you need to explicitly call the narrow character versions of the windows API functions such as `CreateDirectoryA` instead of `CreateDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateDirectoryA`.

That said you'd be better off changing to Unicode in your application, wide text.

---

The original code has some problems:

```
// make path to folder in program data
```

↑ This comment is misleading: the code is about *finding* the path, not creating it.

```
char szPath[MAX_PATH];
```

↑ This buffer is unnecessary, instead, for this code, you should just declare the later variable `std::string fname` here, with specified buffer size.

```
if ( ! SUCCEEDED( SHGetFolderPathA( NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath ) ) )
```

↑ `!SUCCEEEDED` is a misleading rewrite of idiomatic `FAILED`. And `SHGetFolderPath` is deprecated. Instead you should be using `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

```
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Could not open server log - no common data folder " << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

↑ The console output makes this failure handling of little value in a GUI program. Anyway, instead of `cout` you should be using `cerr` or `clog` (they both map to the standard error stream by default). In the `exit` call you should either be using a standard value such as `EXIT_FAILURE`, or supply the `HRESULT` that you got (this is Windows convention, in particular for crashing programs), or for some function, the value that you get from `GetLastError`. Anyway `exit` is far too drastic. You should be either throwing an exception or returning an optional.

```
std::string fname = szPath;
fname +="/Point";
```

↑ Forward slashes are generally supported but still the Windows convention is backslash as item separator.

```
CreateDirectory( fname.c_str(), NULL);
```

↑ The only problem that it doesn't compile with `UNICODE` defined before including `windows.h`. Use `CreateDirectoryA`. Or better, switch to Unicode.

Comment: Hej Alf. Can you elaborate on your comment "switch to Unicode"? What I am looking for is best practice. The rest of the program is written to work on multiple platforms, ie OS X, and 64 bit.

Comment: @user2235373: For a pure Windows app switching to Unicode is as simple as defining `UNICODE` before including `windows.h`, and using wide text, i.e. based on `wchar_t` type, plus a bit of support for console output. For portable code with the wide text approach you need different console output support in Unix-land (essentially just calling `setlocale`). However, using 3rd party Unix-land libraries the wide text only approach is not necessarily feasible. Instead I then recommend an abstraction layer so that the same code uses wide text (UTF-16) in Windows, and narrow text (UTF-8) in *nix